# TripAdvisor interview. Is there a better algorithm than the one I gave?

Tags: java, list, search

Just had a phone interview with TripAdvisor (and didn't make the cut).

I was given the code below and asked to implement `findBestTravelAlert` (in Java).

---

Given a list of TravelAlert objects, find the best travel alert to display for a specific location. See example at http://www.tripadvisor.com/Tourism-g147306-Haiti-Vacations.html

```
 class TravelAlert {
      int id;
      String message;
      int locationId;
 }

 class Location {
      int locationId;
      int parentLocationId; // -1 if no parent, location is hierarchy
      String name;

      static Location findLocation(int locationId) {...}
 }

 class TravelAlertStore {
      private List<TravelAlert> lAlerts; // already populated, static

      // Return null if no alert
      TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {
      // implement this
      }
  }
```

**Examples**: If we have 3 travel alerts, one in Boston, one in Massachusetts, and one in the USA:

- A user looking at a Boston specific page should see the travel alert of Boston and not the one of Massachusetts
- A user looking at a Massachusetts page should see the travel alert of
  Massachusetts
- A user looking at a Newton specific page should see the
  travel alert of Massachusetts
- A user looking at a NYC specific page
  should see the US travel alert
- A user looking at a Montreal specific
  page should see no travel alert.

---

The way I did it was rather naive, but it was all I could come up with under pressure:
Search through the list of `TravelAlerts` and see if the `locationId` matches that of our `locationId`. If not, repeat the search and check for matches with the `locationId` of the parent. If at any point in this process we find a match, return that `TravelAlert`. If we reach the end of the process (i.e. there is no parent location), return `null`.

Here's the code:

```
TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {
    TravelAlert current_alert = searchList(locationId, lAlerts);
    if(current_alert != null) {
        return current_alert;
    }
    else {
        int parentLocationId = findLocation(locationId).parentLocationId;
        if(parent_locId == -1)
            return null;
        else {
            return findBestTravelAlert(parentLocationId);
        }
    }
}
TravelAlert searchList(int locationId, List<TravelAlert> cur_list) {
    if(cur_list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if(cur_list.locationId == locationId) {
        return cur_list;
    }
    else {
        searchList(locationId, cur_list.next())
    }
}
```

The time complexity is *O(nk)*, where *n* is the length of the List of TravelAlerts and *k* is the height of the location hierarchy tree.

---

So, my question is:

> - Is there a better algorithm for doing this, and
> - Is there a better way of implementing my algorithm?

I'm sure the answer to the second question is yes; there must be built-in methods I could have used, were I more familiar with Java.

Any help would be appreciated. Good luck to all future applicants!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Your `searchList()` method doesn't work (or even compile). There is no `locationId` field on `List`, and when you attempt to make the recursive call you are trying to pass an element from the list into the second parameter, where the list is expected.

2) You haven't followed either the Sun de-facto standard coding conventions, or the coding conventions of the example.

3) Generally, recursion is less efficient than looping (because you have to keep lots of stack frames around instead of, say, a single pointer/index into an array) - and since both of your recursive functions are tail-recursive they could both be replaced by loops.

Without building a better data structure (e.g. a `Map` of location id to travel alert), or knowing that the list of travel alerts is sorted (which you would probably have gained some credit for mentioning), you could probably save some time by pre-computing the list of location ids (that is, the chain from the location to the top of the tree) and then walking the travel alert list once (assuming it's considerably bigger than the depth of the location tree) and comparing each alert with the list of location ids to determine the best match.

Answer (score 3):

Using what dty has said, I went and coded the example to see how it would look.

The first step is to convert the List into a hashMap.  The idea is that it takes O(N) to complete this mapping, but after that it is O(1) to lookup a location to see if there is a valid TravelAlert.

Also, as dty pointed out, recursion loads the stack heavily.  A simple while() loop can be used to step through the locationId and all of the potential parentIds.

```
// Return null if no alert
public TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {
    TravelAlert result = null;

    // Convert list to map
    HashMap<Integer,TravelAlert> alertMap = new HashMap<Integer,TravelAlert>();
    for (TravelAlert a : lAlerts) {
        alertMap.put(a.locationId, a);
    }

    // search the map with the given locationId as well as parentIds of the locationId
    while (result == null && locationId > 0) {
        result = alertMap.get(locationId);
        locationId = Location.findLocation(locationId).parentLocationId;
    }

    // TravelAlert returned
    // if there are no more parentIds, result will still be null
    return result;
}
```

Comment: One thing I don't understand about the solution is why you put in the while loop "&& locationId > 0". Logically I guess it makes sense, but the definition above said findLocation will return -1 when there is no result. So why not check for -1 explicitly? Especially since it did not say that other negative numbers could not be valid locationIds. Locations ids could exist between Int.MinValue and -2, as well as from 0 to Int.MaxValue. (I know that  would probably not happen in real life, but still for correctness based on the question I would use -1)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I tried coming up with my solution. It recursively checks parents in the list till the parent becomes -1. Order of `O(n)`

```
class TravelAlertStore {
private List<TravelAlert> lAlerts;

  TravelAlert getLAlert(int locationId) {
   for (TravelAlert t : lAlerts) {
      if(t.locationId == locationId)
        return t;
    }
    return null;
  }

  int findHierarchy(int locationId) {

    if(lAlerts.contains(locationId))
      return locationId;

    int parentLocationId = Location.findLocation(locationId).parentLocationId;
    if(parentLocationId == -1)
      return -1;

    return findHierarchy(parentLocationId);
  }

  TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {

    int bestLocation = findHierarchy(locationId);

    return bestLocation > -1 ? getLAlert(bestLocation) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed it up quite a bit if you attached the alerts to your location tree.  For example (dunno what syntax S.O. thinks this is in...):

```
+ World
  + Canada
    - Montreal
  + United States [A!]
    + Massachusetts [B!]
      - Boston [C!]
    + New York
      - Albany
      - New York City
```

Then, provided you can map a web page to a node in your location tree, all you have to do is work your way up the tree looking for travel alerts.  If you get to the top without seeing any, there aren't any to display.  This'll take your runtime down to `O(k)`, where `k` is the height of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this version of a solution without looking at anyone's answer. Then I looked at the answers and I think Remy's might be better, but it's hard to say because it depends on the data set.

Remy's version does not even call the look up for the parent locations if there is a match for the child location, which is a good thing if looking up locations takes time.

My version looks up the locations and all parent locations first and gives them weights. Then, it traverses the list of alerts and records the best match it found so far along the way. If it gets to something with a weight of zero, it stops traversing and returns immediately.

If doing the location lookup was fast (i.e. also a HashMap) I think my version COULD be better in the situation where there are a ton of travel alerts, and possibly more than one "best match", since you will not have to traverse the first list.

For example there might be 500 entries for Boston. 10,000 for MA. 500,000 for USA. If you are on the Boston page, as soon as you hit one for Boston the method will return.

But, if looking up a location is expensive, Remy's could be better. Because mine looks up all the parents before starting to traverse the list.

```
TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {
    // LocationID mapped to weight (0 is best)
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> pref = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();     
    int weight=0;
    while (locationId != -1)
    {   
        Location loc = Location.findLocation(locationId);
        if (loc == null) {
            // Possibly log an error but don't give up yet
            break; 
        }
        pref.put(locationId,weight);
        weight++;
        locationId = loc.parentLocationId;
    }

    if (pref.size() == 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(String.Format("Could not locate location with id {0}", locationId));
    }

    TravelAlert best=null;
    int bestWeight=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    foreach(TravelAlert ta in lAlerts) {
        Integer wt = pref.get(ta.locationId);
        if (wt != null && wt < bestWeight)
        {
            bestWeight = wt;
            best=ta;            
        }
        if (bestWeight == 0) break;
    }

    return best;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution that may not be the most efficient but will get the job done.

```
TravelAlert findBestTravelAlert(int locationId) {
    for (TravelAlert alert : lAlerts {
        if (alert.locationId == locationId) {
            return alert;
        }
    }
    int parentId = Location.findLocation(locationId).parentLocationId;
    if (parentId == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    return findBestTravelAlert(parentId);
}
```